# Filtering data, check if variable is empty before checking if variable exists in db

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I have a page with 'trips' from which I get back my searchTrip object with all the fields that user has entered. The user might have only entered some of them e.g. *From*, *To* or only *From*, therefore, I need to check if the value is empty and if not then I can use it in my linq query.

Basically if trip *From* value is not set or is null dont check if trips contains it. Same with all the other parameters.

```
var trips = db.Trips
              .Where(u =>
                u.From.Contains(indexControllerViewData.SearchTrip.From) &&
                u.To.Contains(indexControllerViewData.SearchTrip.To) &&
                u.DepartureDate.Equals(indexControllerViewData.SearchTrip.DepartureDate) &&
                u.ReturnDate.Equals(indexControllerViewData.SearchTrip.ReturnDate));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data is returned as properties on the view data, the LINQ statement can be built in a series of like this

```
var searchTrip = indexControllerViewData.SearchTrip;
var trips = db.Trips;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTrip.From))
{
    trips.Where(u => u.From.Contains(searchTrip.From))
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTrip.To))
{
    trips.Where(u => u.To.Contains(searchTrip.To))
}
// ... and so on
```

The basics of the approach is the LINQ statements can be built and `Where` conditions don't have to be specified at once.

Keep in mind, this isn't a great design since any change in the search criteria (adding destination city, perhaps) will require code change.  A more robust solution would be to return the search trip criteria as an array of criteria objects and loop over them -- but that would require much more change up front (possibly extensive) and is outside the scope of your question.  But feel free to ask another if it is something you want to explore.

Comment: Yeah, I think this is what I will stick to this right now. I was thinking about the array but I'm also using many different types DataType, int, floats so It wouldn't be that straight forward.

Comment: Glad you have your answer. The presence of different types is why an array of criteria objects is more straight-forward -- each criteria object knows how to handle the specifics of its case.  It takes a bit more to initially set up, but afterward it is easier.

Answer (score 0):

The way I think is best to do it is to split the call up and check for the form values using if statements. If there are values then amend the query to filter for the value.

For example

```
var trips = db.Trips.Where(u => u.Active) //or what ever initial query you want to do, preferably on a value that is required.

if(indexControllerViewData.SearchTrip.From.hasValue) //check that there is a value (I dont know what type the From value is)
{
  trips = trips.where(u => u.From.contains(indexControllerViewData.SearchTrip.From));
}
```

This doesn't lose efficiency as trips is an IQueryable and the statement on gets executed when called.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Coalesce operator: **??**

```
//usage:
//string notNullValue = table.NullableColumn ?? "";

... u.From.Contains(indexControllerViewData.SearchTrip.From ?? "")...
```

More info here:
[MSDN Coalesce Operator : '??'](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)